# selenium/python i cant select a item in dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, select

I am writing an automation for work and am stuck with a dropdown. The particular select box in question is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKtyl.jpg)

If there is no select, how can I select one of the items?

Comment: hi Gabriel, can you please share your code so far and any error you are experiencing?  -  treat your selenium script as if you were doing it manually, it might not be a `select` but you can click on something, then click on the relevant dropdown?

Comment: The only way I have found to do anything is:

select_provincia = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sui-MoleculeSelect")
select_provincia.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

but once the dropdown has been deployed I don't know how to choose an item.
Thank for your answer

Comment: is it possible for you to share page link  ? If not at least can share HTML code here. Not the image.

Comment: Never mind I have accessed link based on image, please see the working code in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A demo in Java language, just translate to Python by yourself (if you can't, let me know):

```java
WebElement province = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='province']"));

// scroll the page to the element `Provincia`
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", province);

// province.click(); doesn't work, I have not figured out why
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(province).click().perform();

// Notice this is the answer to your question
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li//span[contains(text(),'Granada')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
I am very grateful to you, it has also served me a lot. It is the first time I have asked something but it is worth it for the speed and accuracy of the answers.

Comment: @GabrielGilabert glad the answer is useful to you. Also, here's a tip for you. If `findElement(xx).click()` works, better not to use `actions.xx.click()` or `script("arguments[0].click();",xx)`.

Answer (score 0):

As is is not a select type item, you can first click on arrow in drop down to make available options visible. Then you can use Java script to select desired option from drop down. Reason we use javascript because it might be possible even after clicking on arrow few options may not be in screen freame.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.milanuncios.com/publicar-anuncios-gratis/formulario?c=393")

# Wait for upto 20 sec for page to load completely
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ma-NavigationHeader-logoLink']")))

proviceDropDown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='province']//following-sibling::span")
#Scroll to dropdoen you want to select
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", proviceDropDown)
proviceDropDown.click()


#Assume you are getting province name as parameter, I am doing a static assignment for demonstration 
proviceValue = "Granada"
optionToSelectXPath = "//ul[@class='sui-MoleculeDropdownList sui-MoleculeDropdownList--large']//span[text()='"+ proviceValue +"']")"
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath(optionToSelectXPath ))
```

Comment: Thanks is a real good code and work fine, but in the last sentence How can I put a variable instead of a text 'Granada' to refer to a different population each time.

Comment: I have parameterized xpath, now you can assign any value to proviceValue variable. It will select that province. Please accept and up vote it it helps you solve your problem. Cheers :)