# Selenium webdriver java - Automating Dojo Dropdown - Getting no such element exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, dojo

After clicking one hyperlink in my application. There is a Dojo popup appears mentioned below:
From the dropdown I need to select QA/SIT environment value.

[image]

HTML code for this is mentioned below:

```
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_0" aria-required="true" value="" aria-invalid="false">
```

Now, I tried below code to select the value from dropdown But I am getting no such element exception.

```
Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\\\"dijit_form_FilteringSelect_0\\")));
        drpCountry.selectByIndex(4);
```

I am getting below No such element exception error.
Can anyone please explain what I am missing here. How to Automate Dojo select dropdown

Comment: Select class methods only work for select tag elements. As in HTML shared by you it is not a select class, you are getting this issue. Please share complete HTML consisting of options you want to select, so that i can provide a complete solution. In the mean time I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465281/selenium-python-i-cant-select-a-item-in-dropdown/63467887#63467887

Comment: Hi, I checked your answer , see the issue is in Dojo html you will never find complete select values in drop-down.i will share screenshot tomorrow

Comment: Hi , Rahul Rai, Added HTML snapshot. plse have a look

Comment: Can you please copy paste HTML code than sharing image. It will much easy for me to replicate your issue in my local system

Comment: I have given one solution please check it should work. If Xpath for arrow botton is not correct please correct. As i have guessed it due to unavailability of HTML for this.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am able to click on Dropdown Arrow now. Only problem is selecting value from Dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to select your option. First click on drop down arrow present in there

:[image]

```
String option = "QA/SIT"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner']")).sendKeys(option ) # Choose a valid xpath if its not correct
optionXpath = "//div[text()='"+option+"']"
optEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath(optionXpath ))
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(""arguments[0].click();",optEle );
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have tried that solution.. I am still not able to select the value in dropdown box

Comment: Can you go to element inspection mode F12 -> -Go to source Tab >Click on Arrow - > Press F8 and see what is tag for your element to be selected ?